# Rabies Injections - Visiting Phnom Tamao

Tags: health, cambodia, rabies

I have recently gotten some travel injections for travelling to Cambodia. I am planning to go to Phnom Tamao Wildlife Rescue Centre and was wondering whether I should get rabies vaccinations?

I guess the real question is, anyone who has been to this Rescue Centre before, did you get the rabies vaccinations before you went? If not, did you get bitten? and what was the procedure afterwards? Are the animals free from rabies since they are in the Rescue centre?

I'm a bit uncertain on what do do as the price of the vaccinations is a bit high and any advice would help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I was going to Cambodia I would err on the side of getting rabies shots regardless, because the risk of having a holiday ruined outweighs the cost to my mind - similar to travel insurance.

Rabies is a [huge](http://news.xinhuanet.com/english/health/2013-09/27/c_132756196.htm) [issue](http://www.phnompenhpost.com/lifestyle/surge-demand-rabies-vaccinations-phnom-penh) in Cambodia and vaccinations are recommended for those at risk of [animal](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/cambodia) [bites](http://www.traveldoctor.com.au/files/editor_upload/File/fact-sheets/9115%20TD%20Health%20Fact%20Sheet%20Cambodia.pdf).  From what I can find about the centre, there are [free-ranging monkeys](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g293940-d3373372-r125375052-Phnom_Tamao_Wildlife_Rescue_Center-Phnom_Pen.html) - these are an inherent rabies risk in any SE Asian country, unfortunately.

There is [a treatment course](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/rabies/Pages/treatment.aspx) if you do get bitten but that's going to be more expensive and time-consuming than getting the vaccination in the first place, as it requires multiple injections over the course of a month.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those news articles about rabies make it a bit more real, since I have no clue what is like there. 
Fortunately I decided to get the injections anyway. I was thinking the same as you even without the proof given. 

I'd rather spend the money than slender my holiday in the hospital, and at risk of not getting the RIG shot in time.